# How to serialize this JSON Array String using Jackson Annotations?

Tags: json, parsing, jersey, jackson

> [{"ID":"hzQ8ll","CreationDate":"Thu, 24 Feb 2011 12:53:31 GMT","Count":6,"Name":"SOMETAG"}]

The inside is of type `Tag` so I just wrote this Java class:

```
public class Tags {
    public List <Tag>tags;
}
```

But I get `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException`:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.test.Tags  out of START_ARRAY token
```

I am using Jersey with the `JacksonJsonProvider` like this:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
```

Then I just do a simple Jersey client call:

```
ClientResponse response = builder.get(ClientResponse.class);
Tags tags = response.getEntity(Tags.class);
```

Any ideas? Most of the time my outermost elements had a name associated to it so this is new to me. Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us actual code where you use this?

Comment: See above. I use jersey so there is no real jackson code as i let the provider handle it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You possibly have to declare a `Tag[]` instead of a `List<Tag>`.
I had a similar issue with a different JSON library.
It seems to have to do with difficulties introspecting generic containers.

You have a strange usage of get().

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/UniformInterface.html#get%28java.lang.Class%29

Return and argument type should be the same.

Either:

```
 ClientResponse resp = builder.get(ClientResponse.class);
```

or

```
 Tag[] resp = builder.get(Tag[].class);
```

Anyway, it seems tha the problem is that your JSON data is an array and it is being deserialized into something that is not (Tags).

Try this directly:

```
Tag[] tags = response.getEntity(Tag[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed the List <Tag> tags to Tag []tags and i got the same error.

Comment: yeah sorry about the code. I corrected. I understand that i'm getting a JSON array so i guess my question is how do I define a java object so that Jackson will parse the JSON array correctly? Thanks

Comment: Should be something like Tag[] tags = response.getEntity(Tag[].class); or List<Tag> tags = response.getEntity(List<Tag>.class);

Comment: Tag[] resp = builder.get(Tag[].class) is the correct way. Thanks.
List<Tag>.class is not valid syntax.